# Java - Understanding Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone please explain to me why this prints out 1 2 3 4 5? I figured it would print out 4 3 2 1 0 but my book and eclipse both say I'm wrong.

```
public class whatever {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        xMethod(5);

    }

    public static void xMethod(int n){
        if (n>0){
            xMethod(n-1);
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Runtime evaluation of recursive functions and their stack frames.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is pretty simple, these are the calls

```
main
   xMethod(5)
      xMethod(4)
          xMethod(3)
             xMethod(2)
                 xMethod(1)
                     xMethod(0)
                 print 1
             print 2
          print 3
      print 4
  print 5
```

So you see the prints are 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but can you also explain why the print statement is even called. It looks like it should never be called. @ilomambo

Comment: @BluceRee: Why shouldn't it?  Eventually, every function returns.  (Well, there are a very few that don't, but that's getting technical.)  When the innermost call to `xMethod` returns, the next-to-innermost call will start right back where it left off: right after the call to itself, at the `print`.

Comment: @ilomambo I thought that when the if statement became false that it exited the loop.

Comment: Because this is recursion in action, on each recursion level after `xMethod(n)` returns there is a print statement `System.out.print(n+" ")`, then the level returns to the upper level that called it, and it prints its value, so on until the main level is reached and the program ends.

Comment: @BluceRee The `if` statement is called the stop condition, otherwise the recursion would go on forever with negative values. When `n` reaches 0 the recursion starts to go back to its callers.

Comment: @BluceRee: An exit from a recursive function is rarely as simple as exiting a loop.  :)  All those calls?  They have to return.  The `if` just stops the recursion from continuing, and starts the CPU on its trip back down the call stack.

Comment: Ohhh okay. That makes sense. I appreciate your time, thank you. My teacher doesn't speak good English so it is very hard for me to learn in this class.

Comment: @BluceRee you should go to Mr Teacher personally and ask to explain :)

Answer (score 5):

It's the result of the call stack.  Here's what it would look like after a call with `n = 5`.  Rotate your head about 180 degrees, since the bottom of this call chain is actually the top of the stack.

- xMethod(5)

  - xMethod(4)

    - xMethod(3)

      - xMethod(2)

        - xMethod(1)

          - xMethod(0)

In a recursive call, you have two cases - a base case and a recursive case.  The base case here is when `n == 0`, and no further recursion occurs.

Now, what happens when we start coming back from those calls? That is, what takes place *after* the recursive step?  We start doing `System.out.print()`.  Since there's a condition which prevents both recursion **and** printing when `n == 0`, we neither recurse nor print.

So, the reason that you get `1 2 3 4 5` as output is due to the way the calls are being popped from the stack.

Comment: awesome explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It first call itself recursively and only when the recursive call finishes it prints.
So think about which call finishes first - it's when n = 0.
Then n = 1, etc.

It's a stack and you print after taking from the stack (after the recursion call), so the order is reversed.
If you printed before putting on the stack, then the order is preserved.

Comment: so the stack empties by printing the statements?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print(n + " ");
xMethod(n-1);
```

It will print 5 4 3 2 1. Because It will first print then call xMethod.

And in your case

```
xMethod(n-1);
System.out.print(n + " ");
```

Here it will reach to end condition then poped up and print. so 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 2):

To explain how recursion works, let's see the sample of factorial calculation:

```
int factorial(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return i * factorial(i - 1);
}
```

For example let's get factorial value of 5:

```
int result = factorial(5);
```

Remember that exit value:

```
if (i == 0) {
   return 1;
}
```

and return value:

```
i * factorial(i - 1)
```

Just look at iterations (according to return value):

```
5*factorial(4) -> 4*factorial(3) -> 3*factorial(2) -> 2*factorial(1) -> 1*factorial(0)
```

In fact it is:

```
5*(4*(3*(2*(1*factorial(0)))))
```

cause `factorial(4) == 4*factorial(3), factorial(3) == 3*factorial(2)`, etc.

last iteration is `factorial(0)` that equals `1` (look at exit value).

In result:

```
5*(4*(3*(2*(1*1)))) = 120
```

Answer (score 1):

`xMethod` is called until `n` is `0`. The stack will then be `xMethod(5)->xMethod(4)->xMethod(3)->xMethod(2)->xMethod(1)->xMethod(0)`. As it finishes `xMethod(0)`, it will pop into the next line in `xMethod(1)`, printing `1`. This will then repeat until `xMethod(5)` is exited.

If you went and expanded each `xMethod` as it was called, the code would look something like this:

```
{
    nA = 5 // What n was set at first
    if (nA>0){
        { 
            // Instead of xMethod(n-1), 
            // we're setting nB to nA - 1 and 
            // running through it again.
            nB = nA - 1  // nB is 4

            if (nB>0){
                { 
                    nC = nB - 1 // nC is 3
                    if (nC>0){
                        { 
                            nD = nC - 1 // nD is 2
                            if (nD>0){
                                {
                                    nE = nD - 1 // nE is 1
                                    if (nE>0){
                                        {
                                            nF = nE - 1 // nF is 0.
                                            if (nF>0){
                                                // This will never execute b/c nF is 0.
                                            }
                                        }
                                        System.out.print(nE + " "); // prints 1
                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.print(nD + " "); // prints 2
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.print(nC + " "); // prints 3
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(nB + " "); //prints 4 
            }
        }
        System.out.print(nA + " "); //prints 5
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right...at 10,000 feet.  Could you give a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
   1 public static void xMethod(int n){
   2    if (n>0){ //the base condition
   3         xMethod(n-1); //function is again called with one value less than previous
   4         System.out.print(n + " "); //now print
   5     }
   6  }
```

Now look at line#3, As nothing is printed but the function is again called, so from line#3, the call reaches to line#1 again. which means, n was 5, but the new call takes n = 4 and it keeps going till line#2 tells that n is now less than 0.

When if condition fails at line#2, it reaches at line#5 and then line#6 which means the function has ended execution, and n = 1 at this time.

Now where should the call be returned? at line#3 where the last function was called and it will be popped out from stack executing line#4 which prints the value of n i.e. 1 2 3 4 5.

Answer (score -1):

this
            xMethod(n-1);
            System.out.print(n + " ");

should be:

```
        System.out.print(n + " ");
        xMethod(n-1);
```

Comment: the calls are being made sequentially. So before you ever call `System.out.print(n + " "); your calling xMethod() on every value from  n - 1 to zero. when it becomes less than zero it will not call and xMethod again and will proceed to the next step, in this case the print method. It will then proceed to return to the caller process and do that next step, again the print method. And so on until the it returns to the top of the call stack and executes the last print statement and the program finishes.

Comment: Yes...that's how it *works*. That's not a justification as to why the code should be reversed.

Comment: @JaredCMiller: The point is, the code is a certain way, and it works, but doesn't match what he was expecting.  The OP was asking why that is.  The answer to that question isn't to change the code, but to explain it.

Answer (score -2):

this is the right code

```
System.out.print(n + " ");
xMethod(n-1);
```

Comment: I know that there is nothing wrong with the code. I would just like to know why it does what it does.