# Explain Recursive Function: what if it calls itself two times?

Tags: java, recursion

Explain the given below function line by line. 
Here in recursive function, it calls its self two times. Can any one give detailed explanation of function just like given in this [**[Question].**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941818/java-understanding-recursion?rq=1) Here the difference is, in recursive function body it calls itself two times.
Here is the Code Snippet:

```
public static void fun(int n){

    if(n > 0){

        fun(--n);
        System.out.println(n);
        fun(--n);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
      int a=3;
        fun(a);       

 }
```

I know there are lot of recursion related question discussed here, but I can't able to find the one in which recursive call happens two times in function body. How to understand Recursive Function like this.
Some questions explanation says we have to stack values, then how to stack values for this function?

Comment: Please do your homework yourself, there is a reason for homework.

Comment: Please **at least** execute the code and see what happens.

Comment: I got 0 1 2 0 as a output

Comment: Why closed!! WHY this is not a real question, lots of beginner like me can found this question useful. I really don't understand in 0 1 2 0, the last zero is in the output. How to do homework what do you mean by that? I've read about recursion but this is kind of different. I think this is the place where I can find help. You have to think first from the perspective of the beginner. I have learned that we have to put values in stack then reaching the base popping is done but here again there is a function call, so can't able to understand that fun call on line 6 can again call fun on line 3?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than imagining a stack of calls to the function, imagine a tree. The first call to the function is the root of the tree. Each of the first recursive calls to the tree will create a branch on the left, and the second recursive call will create a branch to the right. What you'll see is that the left branch will be a straight line until the base case is reached, then right branches will start appearing, each growing leftwards until they reach their base cases.

Basically it will execute exactly as you would expect if you walked through it in your head and "played computer"