# Simple java recursion, Can someone help me understand the logic going on in the stack memory?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm doing some self study on DS + algos on udemy and I'm having a hard time grasping recursion. I have posted a method that will take an array and index and return the maximum sum that can be achieved following the rule that the elements chosen can't be perpendicular.

In the example arr = {6, 7, 1, 30, 8, 2, 4} the answer is 7, 30, 4 = 41. I've included some prints to help me understand what's going on, but I get lost after the first math.max() return

```
public class House_Thieft_DC {

    public int maxMoney(int[] HouseNetWorth) {
        return maxMoneyRecursive(HouseNetWorth, 0);
    }//end of method

    private int maxMoneyRecursive(int[] HouseNetWorth, int currentIndex) {
        if (currentIndex >= HouseNetWorth.length) 
            return 0;

        System.out.println("HouseNetWorth: "+HouseNetWorth[currentIndex]);
        
        int stealCurrentHouse = HouseNetWorth[currentIndex] + maxMoneyRecursive(HouseNetWorth, currentIndex + 2);
        int skipCurrentHouse = maxMoneyRecursive(HouseNetWorth, currentIndex + 1);
        
        System.out.print("stealCurrentHouse: "+stealCurrentHouse);      
        System.out.print("    skipCurrentHouse: "+skipCurrentHouse);
        System.out.println("    max: "+Math.max(stealCurrentHouse, skipCurrentHouse)+"\n");

        return Math.max(stealCurrentHouse, skipCurrentHouse);
    }//end of method

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        House_Thieft_DC ht = new House_Thieft_DC();
        int[] HouseNetWorth = {6, 7, 1, 30, 8, 2, 4}; //ans is 7, 30, 4 = 41
        System.out.println(ht.maxMoney(HouseNetWorth));
        //HouseNetWorth = new int[] {20, 5, 1, 13, 6, 11, 40};
        //System.out.println(ht.maxMoney(HouseNetWorth));
    }
}// end of class
```

Comment: Maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941818/java-understanding-recursion

Answer (score 0):

As each of the calls is based on an item further right, it helps to calculate from right to left the result of `maxMoneyRecursive`

6, 7, 1, 30, 8, 2, 4

should be

41, 41, 34, 34, 12, 4, 4

To understand and log better the flow of the calculation, it might be helpful to add a parameter for the calling loop like

```
private int maxMoneyRecursive(int[] HouseNetWorth, int currentIndex, int callingIndex)
```

if you always fill the `callingIndex` with the `currentIndex` you will see where each calculation is coming from.